# Manual override switch design with mosfet and DPTP

Tags: switches, identification

I want to design a bathroom light that automatically adjust color and brightness according to many factors (time of the day, people presence, mood, weather...) but I don't trust myself with electronics so I want to design a foolproof way to override my device so that I can normally switch lights.

Fort this design I would like to use two switches. The first switch is a dpdt that will activate the manual override, and the second switch will actually operate the light (provided override is active, otherwise it should not do anything).

[image: circuit]

Is it possible to build such circuit with commercial switches such that it will blend with normally used switches like in the picture? How are they called?

[image: switches]

Comment: You can do this with a "3 way" switch, and a regular switch if you change the circuit a little bit.

Comment: I’m listening...

Comment: 4 way lighting switch has only 4 terminals. You need 6. In your drawing manual override looks like two 3-way switches. It will be two buttons. Why just not to put one 3-way switch before transistor?

Comment: I corrected the question text, it's a DPTP switch

Comment: I think you mean DPDT but you had me puzzled for a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "3 way" switch for domestic wiring, plus a regular switch should be able to do this:

[image: circuit diagram]

Comment: This looks much better than my design. I’ll examine it and probably accept the answer.